# zxing.net c# can't change the width of the barcode in a flowdocument

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing, flowdocument

I'm using visual studio c# and zxing.net library to encode some numbers then print it using flowdocuments.

first i used the BarcodeWriter class in zxing.net to save it as a bitmap then I transformed it into a BitmapImage through this method :

```
        private BitmapSource Bitmap2BitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapSource i = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                       bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                       IntPtr.Zero,
                       Int32Rect.Empty,
                       BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        return i;
    }
```

I got it from a thread in here, then I added it to the flowdocument through InlineUIContainer .

This is the code :

```
 public void Print(string[] strArray)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Image barcodeimg = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();

        BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter();
        writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
        writer.Options.PureBarcode = true;
        writer.Options.Width = 40;
        writer.Options.Height = 6;
        MessageBox.Show(strArray[1].ToString());
        string BID = strArray[1];
        Bitmap mmm = writer.Write(BID.ToString());


        FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Section sec = new Section();

        flowDoc.ColumnWidth = 2000;
        int x = Properties.Settings.Default.X;
        int y = Properties.Settings.Default.Y;
        int fontSize = Properties.Settings.Default.fontSize;

        sec.Padding = sec.Margin = new Thickness(x,y,0,0);
        sec.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        sec.FontSize = fontSize ;

        double lineH = Properties.Settings.Default.LineHighet;

        barcodeimg.Source = Bitmap2BitmapImage(mmm);
        InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer(barcodeimg);
        container.FontStretch = FontStretches.ExtraCondensed;
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(container);
        sec.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        flowDoc.Blocks.Add(sec);

        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = flowDoc;
        dialog.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator,"job1");
    }
```

The problem is the printed barcode width won't change, it changes a little bit when i change numbers but not even close to what I'm looking for.

Here is different tries of different sizes, you can see the height changes but the width is almost the same.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZsSm.jpg

I'm new here so excuse me for any mistakes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

probably to late but...

Barcodes are just a set of black bars with some white spaces between and the thickness of black bars and the white space between them is what defines the digits.
That beeing said, proportions must be kept.

When you are setting the width and height of "writer.Options", you are realy just setting the grid resolution of the barcode. Try to set to 800 x 600 (or more) and you see that the width will not change, you will only get better image quality.

I dont know how you`re printing the barcode, but probably your problem resides there and not on the barcode construction.